# How to make bootstrap dropdowns transition opacity

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanted to make the dropdown-menu in Bootstrap fade in rather than just immediately popping up.

I have tried this to make it work but it only fades in when I hover over the dropdown (which is invisible until I do so, even when the dropdown button is selected):

```
.nav-pills > li > a { border: 1px solid #242323 }
.nav-pills > li.active > a,
.nav-pills > li > a:hover, .nav-pills > li > a:focus,
.nav-pills > li.active > a:hover, .nav-pills > li.active > a:focus {
  color: #00BFFF;
  background-color: #242323;
  border: 1px solid #00BFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.nav-pills .open > a, .nav-pills .open > a:hover, .nav-pills .open > a:focus {
  background-color: #242323;
  border: 1px solid #00BFFF;
  color: #00BFFF;
}

.blog-top > .align-left > .nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a { color: #E0E0E0 }
.blog-top > .align-left > .nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li:hover > a {
  color: #00BFFF;
  background-color: #404040;
}

.blog-top > .align-left > .nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #242323;
  border: 1px solid #00BFFF;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transition: .25s, transform .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: .25s, transform .25s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .25s, transform .25s ease;
}

.blog-top > .align-left > .nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu:hover { opacity: 1 }

[aria-expanded=true].dropdown-toggle + ul.dropdown-menu { opacity: 1 }
```

I have also tried putting `opacity: 1;` on individual `a:focus` elements but that doesn't seem to help.

This is a sample of what the HTML looks like:

```
<div class="blog-top">
  <div class="align-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">

      <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MENU <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set them to `opacity: 0` and `visiblity:hidden` or `z-index: -1` **by default**.

Then, on hover and using css transitions, set them to `opacity: 1` and `visibility:visible` or `z-index: 1`.

By the way, the direct child selector (>) is overly specific. You shouldn't use it everytime.

Here is a code snippet. See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qrg9mau/) to see it working with Bootstrap 3.

```css
.nav-pills li a {
  border: 1px solid #242323
}

.nav-pills li.active > a,
.nav-pills li a:hover,
.nav-pills li a:focus,
.nav-pills li.active a:hover,
.nav-pills li.active a:focus {
  color: #00BFFF;
  background-color: #242323;
  border: 1px solid #00BFFF;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.nav-pills .open a,
.nav-pills .open a:hover,
.nav-pills .open a:focus {
  background-color: #242323;
  border: 1px solid #00BFFF;
  color: #00BFFF;
}

.nav .dropdown-menu li a {
  color: #E0E0E0
}

.nav .dropdown-menu li:hover a {
  color: #00BFFF;
  background-color: #404040;
}

.nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #242323;
  border: 1px solid #00BFFF;
  opacity: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  transition: .25s, transform .25s ease;
  -moz-transition: .25s, transform .25s ease;
  -webkit-transition: .25s, transform .25s ease;
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}

[aria-expanded=true].dropdown-toggle + ul.dropdown-menu,
.nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu.show {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blog-top">
  <div class="align-left">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">

      <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">MENU <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Item</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't work. I set the `opacity: 0` and `visibility: hidden` in the `.dropdown-menu {` style and the `opacity: 1` with `visibility: visible` in the last two syles in my sheet separately.

Comment: It wasn't doing the animation because it was transitionning from `display: none` to `display: block` which is his default behavior. Set it to `display: block` by default first as shown in my updated answer.

Comment: I don't know why but it's still not working even though I copied your code exactly.

Comment: Did you check my jsfiddle ? Use the inspector to see if other styles are preventing this from working correctly.

Comment: Yeah, I checked the JSFiddle and it works there but not in my code. I also checked and it didn't seem that anything was conflicting with the class via Chrome code inspector.

Comment: If it works on my js-fiddle but not on your website, something must be affecting it on your end. Either your HTML, your CSS or your JS. Did you make sure that `.nav .dropdown .dropdown-menu` was set to `display: block` ?

Comment: Yes, I actually just copied and pasted your jsfiddle's CSS and replaced my section with it. I also checked my JS files and nothing seems to be interacting with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190249/discussion-between-jake-and-jake).

Answer (score 0):

Use animate.css - works well with Bootstrap. https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/